# How to auth Javascript frontend for REST API queries?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm starting to create application that contains a lot of javascript widgets that consume some external json from REST API.

So I'm stuck at authentication part. To get API response i need to pass username and password in header so the question is how should i do it without exposing username/password in code?

For now all i can think of is to create a php script where user login form will save user/password  (if valid) into session, and then i will create another php script that will work like a proxy for all api calls ( curl that adds header with user and password ) .

Any better ideas how to do this ?

Comment: Are you working with an external REST web service? Or is it your own WS?

Comment: If it's on the same server/domain (and I guess it is, since you can make an ajax request) the WS should be able to check if the user is already logged in